# Tail recursion in a monadic function

Tags: haskell, monads, tail-recursion

I wanted to transform the folowing `genEdges` function in a tail recursive one.

```
genEdges :: Int -> Node -> IO [Edge]
genEdges n origin | n == 0 = return []
                  | otherwise =  do
                      edge <- genRandEdge origin
                      edges <- genEdges (n-1) (snd edge)
                      return $ edge : edges
```

I mean, the last line should be something like

```
return $ edge : genEdges (n-1) (snd edge)
```

although I know that the types of `edge` and `genEdges (n-1) (snd edge)` are different and hence this example line is incorrect.

Is that possible? If so, how should be the function? If not, why?

Comment: Tail recursion is a red herring in Haskell anyway, because its evaluation model is so different from traditional languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible. Your tail call is really

```
(genRange origin) >>= (\edge -> .....)
```

and hence it is not recursive.

----------- Edit for updated question -----------------

Generally, if you have something like

```
do
  a <- foo
  bar
```

you can't make something tail recursive out of it. This is because this gets desugared to

```
foo >>= (\a -> bar)
```

so (>>=) (or (>>)) is the tail call.

Comment: So the question changes to: is that possible to do a tail recursion `edge : genEdges (n-1) (snd edge)` and not use `return`? Because I'd like to have a `[Edge]`, not a `IO [Edge]`, but my `Edge`s are "trapped" inside an `IO` monad since I'm working with random numbers (`System.Random` functions such as `getStdRandom` and `randomR`).

Comment: You shouldn't be trapped in the IO monad in first place, there are better approaches.

Comment: One minor quibble; it's not really impossible.  The "solution" isn't generally advised, and there are definitely better approaches, but it does exist.

Comment: @JohnL If you mean to say that one can have a non-trivial and terminating tail recursive function with IO type, I ask you kindly to post an answer and tell us how. I'd surely upvote.

Comment: @Ingo: no, that's not what I meant. What I meant was that the OP could add a single function call and have exactly the desired code with good performance characteristics for the Haskell evaluation model.  I don't think you'd upvote, it's a function with `Interleave` in the name...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Looking at Ingo's answer he is right, you'd probably have to pass the generator into the function then you can use a pure function to get the next random number and pass the gen that it produces to the next recursive function call.

**END EDIT**

You can make a helper function that has an accumulator so like this.  I don't have a compiler so I can't guaranteed it is exactly correct.

```
genEdges :: Int -> Node -> IO [Edge]
genEdges n o = genEdgesTR n o []
    where genEdgesRec n origin acc
          | n == 0  = return acc
          | otherwise   = do
            edge <- get RandEdge orgin
            genEdgesRec (n-1) (snd edge) (edge : acc)
```

This could probably be written with `foldM` or something but that is up to you to figure out.

Comment: You also need to reverse the resulting list in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you end up using `IO` or other monad/monad transformer such as `RandT` (other options are passing generators and/or pregenerated infinite lists around), here is an example of using the state monad transformer to help with threading of `origin`:

```
import Control.Monad.State

data Node = Node
type Edge = ((), Node)

genRandEdge :: Node -> IO Edge
genRandEdge = undefined

genEdges :: Int -> Node -> IO [Edge]
genEdges n = evalStateT $ replicateM n $ do
        origin <- get
        edge <- liftIO $ genRandEdge origin
        put $ snd edge
        return edge
```

To help you with better `genRandEdge` to avoid IO we need more context so feel free to ask another question on how your generation approach can be improved.